# How to create/integrate a qml file into qt-widgets app?

Tags: qt

I have an application developed in Qt4, with current display window designed in xml design sheets. I want to create a new window for the application, using QML to design the interface. Is that possible? Does it require a Qt5 to integrate the new qml file into the existing qt-widgets app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have some working QWidget based code:

```
auto* container = new QQuickWidget(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:main.qml")));
container->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);

auto* layout = new QVBoxLayout(_ui->widget);
layout->addWidget(container);
```

Comment: Note that the use of [`QQuickWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html) requires Qt 5.3 or later.

Comment: I missed that detail :)

Comment: What if I'm using a Qt4.10? Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @Enya Maybe this will work:
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-declarative-tutorials-extending-chapter2-methods-main-cpp.html